# Connect Access to Excel, use Excel userform to update Access record

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, userform

I know it's not recommended but my hands are tied so I have to use this for now (as a patch until I fix the database)

I am in a multi-user environment. The data is on Access and they need to access it to update some information so other department can pull reports and use the newly updated data.

Fairly simple, however, the database wasn't maintained for over 6 months, the infrastructure was bad from the beginning but I can't afford to refactor now.

I have create a userform on Excel where I can update, modify info on sheets. I want to be able to pull the information from access into the excel sheets, and show a userform to the different users, they will update what they have to update and upon closing the userform, the access record they were working on will be updated.

I haven't find any solution for that. I seemed to have find something with DAO but I'm not sure.

Comment: whats the point of the userform if youre just going to put it in the sheet and then back into acces?

Comment: easy for the users to enter the information and also to control what they do change and don't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a super crude example of how to use a userform to write sql. Make sure you have the correct references.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim vAr$
    Dim arrResults(2) As String

    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
            tdf.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next

    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop" & "\" & "xyzmanu3.accdb")

    vAr = TextBox1.Value

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT PartName, PartNum, Quantity FROM InventoryTbl WHERE PartName='" & vAr & "';")

    i = 0
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        arrResults(i) = rst.Fields(0)
        arrResults(i) = rst.Fields(1)
        arrResults(i) = rst.Fields(2)
        rst.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    TextBox2.Value = arrResults(0)
    TextBox3.Value = arrResults(1)
    TextBox4.Value = arrResults(2)

    Set tdf = Nothing
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim vAr$: vAr = TextBox1.Value
    Dim vAr2$: vAr2 = TextBox2.Value
    Dim vAr3$: vAr3 = TextBox3.Value
    Dim vAr4$: vAr4 = TextBox4.Value
    Dim vbSql$

    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
            tdf.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next

    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop" & "\" & "xyzmanu3.accdb")

    vbSql = "UPDATE InventoryTbl SET PartName='" & vAr2 & ", Quantity='" & vAr4 & " WHERE PartNum='" & vAr3 & "';"
    db.Execute vbSql

    Set tdf = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Button1 retrieves the data, stores into an array and then dumps contents into textboxes. Button two takes contents from textboxes and then up;dates the tables based off of that.

Since this isn't a script writing service, you should be able to tinker your way into what you're looking for off of this.

Comment: @DrD4rk make sure to give a guy a thumbs up and a answet check mark :)

Comment: Thank you very much. if you don't mind me asking, how did you know how to do that?  I know a bit of  sql and am very new to excel/access vba userform ... Is there a book i could read to get better at this? Thank you again

Comment: @DrD4rk honestly most of the books dont go into the detail you'd like. Most of them really only scratch the surface, especially if youre looking for more detailed stuff.  Most of what ive learned as been through trial /error, forum/SO trolling and reading the object browser in visual studio(with google to learn more on each item). I havent seen a book that teaches you the update tables loop (very important for what youre doing). But the rest has come from the experience of "just doing it."

Comment: if you need a book, i would get John Walkenbach's book for vba. "Power PRogramming With VBA." But in my opinion learning and understand the object model will teach you more once you "get it."

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will definitely pick up this book to learn more. If you don't mind if i pick your brain some more, but I used the code you gave me and I realized it's not gonna work. To explain quickly, I have 15 clients for 400 projects in total, each clients have their own project and can't see the others for "privacy reasons". my clients are all scattered across the country, some are on my network, some are not, the one that are with a shared folder don't have necessarily the same path to the database...

Comment: So I'm wondering, if there's a way from my end, to pull specific data from the db base on their userID, load separate worksheets with them, send them the workbook protected with a password based on their username, have them use the userform to update whatever they have to, send me back the workbook and I then upload it back to Access. I realized it's a less than ideal situation, unfortunately I inherited this and have to work with it cause deadline until I find a more efficient way of dealing with this. Thank you for any help and suggestion

Comment: Well that would require quite a few changes to your situation. However, should be easy for you to figure out. THe SELECT statement could be conditional based on userID, but if you have 400ish clients the initial set up would be the biggest undertaking. Then you have to figure out how to centrally host your data source, or create various linked access files. The easiest solution wouldbe be a web hosted situation, like an access app stored in sharepoint. That would circumvent the userfomr all together (b/c the access app would be that), but that might be a significant undertaking for you.

Comment: @DrD4rk this book does walk you through the access app thing though https://www.amazon.com/Professional-Access-Programming-Teresa-Hennig/dp/1118530837

Comment: because of how the organization I work with is set up right now, I can't use sharepoint. I'll use your code example, pick up the two books you suggested and try to figure out the best way to deal with that. Again, thank you for your help. I really appreciate the help :)